# Node Analysis with reference point question

Tags: electric-circuits, potential, electrical-resistance

[image]

The reference point was chosen to be at $V_a$.

Using Ohm's law at $i_{R1}$, if $V_a$ is the reference point, it is zero voltage. All the nodes are using it as a reference to ground and my understanding is that the voltage at the node is based on the higher potential minus the lower potential. If that's the case, how can the higher potential be the reference point when it was given a value of zero with respect to all other nodes?

Comment: Hi and welcome to the Physics SE! Please note that we don't answer homework or worked example type questions. Please see [this Meta post on asking homework/exercise questions](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/714/how-do-i-ask-homework-questions-on-physics-stack-exchange) and [this Meta post for "check my work" problems](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/6093/should-any-check-my-work-questions-be-made-on-topic).

Comment: Its not really a homework question as the lectures explain the steps and its shown in the picture as well. I'm questioning the logic behind the reference node being the higher potential. Without working through and follow the work example type, how do we know that we dont understand something like we think we do? this is consider off topic?

Comment: I've edited the question leaning toward more conceptual.

Comment: You need to get used to the idea that the reference potential can be anywhere in the circuit that you choose. It could be the highest or the lowest potential, or anywhere in between.

Comment: This isn't really a homework question anymore. Reviewers, please read all the way through the question!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Negative signs can sometimes cause confusion as can "forgetting" the sign convention which is being used in circuit problems.

[image]

The voltage source symbol with the plus and minus signs inside the circle with the label $V_{\rm S}$ by the side of it means the the potential of the $+$ side is higher than the potential of the $-$ side by $V_{\rm S}$.

$v_{\rm a}, \, v_{\rm b}$ and $v_{\rm c}$ are the potentials of nodes $A, \, B$ and $C$.
The numerical values of these potentials can be positive, negative or zero.

When you draw arrows to represent a current direction it implies that for a resistor the current is flowing from a high potential to a lower potential.

So as drawn $v_{\rm a} > v_{\rm b}$ and $v_{\rm b} > v_{\rm c}$.

On the right-hand side is a potential diagram for this circuit.

Using the convention stated above one can write:

$v_{\rm a} - v_{\rm c} = V_{\rm S}$

$v_{\rm a} - v_{\rm b} = i_{\rm R1}\,R_1$

$v_{\rm b} - v_{\rm c} = i_{\rm R2}\,R_2$

All that remains to be done is to choose a zero of potential which in your case was $v_{\rm a} =0$.

The equations which are in the text that you have provided then follow.

What might be confusing is the term $v_{\rm b} -(-V_{\rm S})$ but what you must remember here is that $v_{\rm b}$ has a negative value and $-V_{\rm S}$ is even more negative (on the assumption that $V_{\rm S}$ is positive).

On the potential diagram you will see that in turn each of the nodes have been made zero and some corresponding numerical values for the potentials have been added.

If $v_{\rm a} = 0$ then $v_{\rm b} - v_{\rm c} = v_{\rm b} -(-V_{\rm S}) = -2-(-3) = +1$

If $v_{\rm b} = 0$ then $v_{\rm b} - v_{\rm c} = 0-(-1) = +1$

If $v_{\rm c} = 0$ then $v_{\rm b} - v_{\rm c} = +1-0 = +1$

So in each case the potential of node $B$ is higher than that of node $C$ by $1$ volt.

Comment: First off thank you for the explanation.
It’s making more sense to me now that the higher potential minus lower potential still hold and you’re just arbitrary pick a reference node to use as a reference when comparing the nodes. 
It is more critical that you understand the potential difference between all the nodes in the circuit then which node is the reference point as it is arbitrary. 1 of 2

Comment: You’re correct that the convention sign and negative signs are confusing, like Vb has a negative value. What does that mean when your potential difference or your pushing force is negative?
Next, the potential difference between Vb and Vc is always will be 1V regardless of what values Vb and Vc are. 
At node A is when you will have your highest potential. As the current flow in the circuit and meet resistance for each branch, the potential voltage will drop.  Could you elaborate on your potential diagram graph? like the colored values and how come node c intercepted the graph twice?  2 of 2

Comment: @Ace8888 A vertical column of the same colour has a particular node as the reference and then the potentials of the other two nodes are shown relative to the reference node. You will note that the potential difference between nodes B and C is always 1 volt and that between A and B is always 2 volts irrespective of where the zero of potential was chosen.

Comment: For color blue, the PD between Vb and Vc is -1 but it is the magnitude of difference which is still 1 that we're observing. The Y axis is voltage and the axis is with respect to time? Correct me if Im wrong; at t=0 C has the lowest PD but as current flow and PD climb point A is the highest PD in the circuit and it drop as it move through all the resistance. thank you for your help!

Comment: @Ace8888 The potential of node B relative to node C is +1 volt and the potential of node C relative to node B is -1 volt. It is a **diagram** of potential against **position in the circuit** (node). Notice that it starts and finishes at the same node.